# R: How to merge multiple data frames when some columns have different names

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, readr

I am trying to merge some csv files into one large data frame using the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)

list_of_files = list.files(path = "/home/maanan/Downloads/NYCData/2017/", recursive = TRUE, pattern = "\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE)

df = readr::read_csv(list_of_files)
```

The code above works fine when the column names are the same. But when I try to merge data sets which have different column names it gives me the following error:

```
Error: Files must have consistent column names:                                                                                                                               
* File 1 column 1 is: Trip Duration
* File 4 column 1 is: tripduration
```

I am trying to combine 12 monthly data sets, 6 of them have names like this:

```
"Trip Duration"  "Start Time" "Stop Time" "Start Station ID" "Start Station Name"
```

The other 6 data sets have names like this:

```
"tripduration"  "starttime"  "stoptime"  "start station id"  "start station name"
```

I would be grateful if someone could help me solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify different name columns by using `by.x` and `by.y` where x and y are the data frames.

Just `?merge` to see how to use them.

Comment: `read_csv` allows me to read and compile multiple files into one data frame without importing them into `r` environment, and this is crucial for me because my computer's memory is limited and the files are very large. `merge` cannot read and merge at the same time.